# download a database sql file from the server

Tags: mysql, sql, database, command-line, putty

I am fairly new to putty command lines. I just export the database of my Drupal site as sql file used the follow line:

mysqldump -p -u website website > drupaldatabase.sql

I input the password as requested later.

Now I want to download this file to my local computer, what command line shall I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your local computer runs under Unix, use scp command line utility, under Windows use pscp.exe

Command line for pscp.exe should look something like

```
pscp.exe youruser@server:/path/to/file C:\path_to_file
```

And you can always download using FTP client if you have FTP server up and running

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do that often, I'd also suggest 'winscp' which does 'SCP' within a GUI.

(If you use pageant with public/private keys you can logon without password as well as with putty, quite convenient)